# Answer Set Programming - Make a Fact INVALID

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic

I have a question regarding **Answer Set Programming** on how to make an existing ***fact*** invalid, when there is already (also) a ***default statement*** present in the Knowledge Base.

For example, there are two persons `seby` and `andy`, one of them is able to drive at once. The scenario can be that `seby` can drive as seen in Line 3 but  let's say, after his license is cancelled he cannot drive anymore, hence we now have Lines 4 to 7 and meanwhile `andy` learnt driving, as seen in Line 7. Line 6 shows only one person can drive at a time, besides showing `seby` and `andy` are not the same.

```
1 person(seby).
2 person(andy).
3 drives(seby).
4 drives(seby) :- person(seby), not ab(d(drives(seby))), not -drives(seby).
5 ab(d(drives(seby))).
6 -drives(P) :- drives(P0), person(P), P0 != P.
7 drives(andy).
```

In the above program, Lines 3 and 4 contradict with each other, and the Clingo solver (which I use) obviously outputs `UNSATISFIABLE`. It can be understood that Line 4 is added to overwrite Line 3 with Line 7.

Having said all this, please don't say to delete Line 3 and the problem is solved. The intention behind asking this question is to know whether it is possible now to make Line 3 somehow invalid to let Line 4 do its duty, i.e., Line 7 to overwrite Line3.

However, Line 4 can also be written as:

```
4 drives(P) :- person(P), not ab(d(drives(P))), not -drives(P).
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here.

Comment: Oh really? My bad! A user has suggested me to post it here on [AIStackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/answer-set-programming-make-a-fact-invalid). Hence I did it.

Comment: @Kodiologist let's get serious,Is this question off-topic.provided that we check community guidelines.

Comment: @Ram yes,this question has to be shared with this community.

Comment: @quintumnia : thanks for your concern man. I hope to get an answer one day :)

Comment: @Ram This question is nice.just because it requires some a little bit concentration.it's logic.

Comment: @quintumnia : actually as far as my knowledge is concerned, and others from my uni, it is not possible. Some call it trivial. But still I have a ray of hope!

Comment: @Ram Just hold onto it,you're going to get an answer.

Comment: @quintumnia: ya sure :)